# What does it mean for a set of sentences $\mathcal{T}$ to "secure" a set of sentences $\Delta$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know the standard interpretation is:

> $\mathcal{T}$ secures $\Delta$ iff every interpretation that makes all
>   members of $\mathcal{T}$ true makes at least one member of $\Delta$
>   true.

However, I'm having trouble understanding the following results:

$\mathcal{T} \models \Delta$ iff $\mathcal{T}$ secures $\{\Delta\}$

$\mathcal{T}$ is unsatisfiable iff $\mathcal{T}$ secures $\emptyset$

$\Delta$ is valid iff $\emptyset$ secures $\{\Delta\}$

In particular, the second and third results are hard to interpret. For the second, if $\mathcal{T}$ secures $\emptyset$, that means that every interpretation that makes all of $\mathcal{T}$ true makes at least one member of $\emptyset$ true. Does this imply that $\mathcal{T}$ is unsatisfiable because there is no interpretation in which $\emptyset$ can be true, so there is no interpretation which makes all of $\mathcal{T}$ true? Does "satisfiable" for a set of sentences imply that all of it's members must be true? I thought this was what "valid" was used for.

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: Without knowing the context where you saw this, it is impossible to say. "secure" is not a standard term, but it has various meanings in English that could have been intended.

Comment: @CarlMummert Sorry, the question was posted before I could include the necessary details. I've done so now.

Comment: @user1038665: thanks. If I can ask one more clarification, in the first one, should $\Delta$ be $D$?

Comment: @CarlMummert edited! The $D$ should have been $\Delta$.

Comment: Yes to both questions. As regards the second, validity is when _all_ interpretations satisfy the set of sentences; satisfiability is only when _some_ interpretation satisfies the set. In other words, the "all" in the definition of validity is not about the _members_ of the set, but about the _interpretations_.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Thanks for clearing that up. Now the second statement makes sense, but I'm still struggling with the third. Take $\emptyset$ secures $\{\Delta\}$; there is no interpretation which makes all of $\emptyset$ true, so how does this imply that every interpretation makes all of $\Delta$ true?

Comment: @user1038665 Glad it helped. In the third one, since ∅ has no members, "every interpretation that [blah blah blah]" is equivalent to "every interpretation", without the "blahs". So if Δ is indeed valid, then every interpretation should secure it.

Comment: I think that $\Delta$ is correct in the highlighted definition of "secures", but that in stating the "results" we need $D$ instead, due also to the fact that $\Delta$ is already a *set* of sentences: thus, there is no need of writing $\{ \Delta \}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the important issue in the second and third items is that $\emptyset$ has no members. Thus is it impossible to secure $\emptyset$, because the definition of "secure" requires satisfying at least one member. On the other hand, every structure satisfies $\emptyset$, because the definition of "satisfies" is that the structure satisfies every formula in the set, and it is trivially the case that every formula in $\emptyset$ is satisifed.

Answer (score 3):

This terminology is used in George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, *Computability and Logic* (5th ed - 2007), Ch.14 : Proofs and Completeness, regarding *sequent calculus*, page 167 :

> We say that one set of sentences $\Gamma$ *secures* another set of sentences $\Delta$ if every interpretation that makes all sentences in $\Gamma$ true makes some sentence in $\Delta$ true.(Note that when the sets are finite, $\Gamma = \{ C_1, . . . ,C_m \}$ and $\Delta = \{ D_1, . . . , D_n \}$, this amounts to saying that every interpretation that makes $C_1 \land. . . \land C_m$ true makes $D_1 \lor · · · \lor D_n$ true: the elements of $\Gamma$ are being taken *jointly* as premisses, but the elements of $\Delta$ are being taken *alternatively* as conclusions, so to speak.)

The condition is clearly a version of the semantical valuation of *sequents* : $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$ [compare with Stephen Cole Kleene, *Mathematical Logic* (1967), page 290 : an interpretation *falsify* (or refute) a sequent $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$ when all of $\Gamma$ are *true* and all of $\Delta$ are *false*; thus, the negation of this definition will be : if all of $\Gamma$ are *true*, then at least one of $\Delta$ is *true*].

BBJ states in Table 14-1 the equivalences between *Metalogical notions* [page 168] :

> > $D$ is a consequence of $\Gamma$ if and only if $\Gamma$ secures $\{ D \}$
> >
> > $\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable if and only if $\Gamma$ secures $\emptyset$
> >
> > $D$ is valid if and only if $\emptyset$ secures $\{ D \}.$

The basic *metalogical notions* are the standard ones :

> $D$ is a *consequence* of $\Gamma$ if, for every interpretations $I$ such that all $\gamma \in \Gamma$ are *true* in $I$, also $D$ is *true* in $I$
>
> $\Gamma$ is *satisfiable* if there is an interpretation $I$ such that all $\gamma \in \Gamma$ are *true* in $I$
>
> $D$ is *valid* if it is *true* in all interpretations.

Comment: I knew I had read 'secures' somewhere; BBJ it is.